# WPF - Manage UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, .net-3.5

I want to make something like this type of UI:

[image: UI]

There will be two or three buttons always on top with a textbox (no change after window resize).

How can I do this in [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation), actually am new to WPF and I want to do this strictly in .Net & WPF 3.5.

Comment: Get a book, follow a tutorial; this stuff is way too complicated to learn through question and answer.

Comment: Any hint would be highly appreciated... I want just the direction to move..

Comment: I would suggest looking into WPF grid this tutorial should get you started.https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/grid-layout-in-wpf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember when I started to learn WPF. It was a steep learning curve.  You need to look into XAML files to get the UI.  For your requirement, the code would look like this...assume you have some background in VS, start new WPF project ect.  What you want is some grid and then you can either drag and drop from Toolbox, or you can just type code for your UI elements.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
    <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
    <TextBox Text="Textbox" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
    <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Grid.Column="1" Height="100" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">            
    </Border>

</Grid>
```

Comment: I found something other than your suggestion too, i.e. DockPanel.. For someone who is newbie like me....